# How do I execute PowerShell Scripts on all computers in an ActiveDirectory's OU?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-remoting

I have the following PowerShell script I would like to execute on all computers in my workplace, to do this I need to execute it on all computers in a specific OU in our company's AD IE: `SearchBase "OU=Location,OU=Corporate,DC=corp,DC=corporation,DC=com"`
`
The script is as follows

```
 `$SourceFilePath = "place"
$ShortcutPath = "C:\Users\nameofplace.lnk"
$WScriptObj = New-Object -ComObject ("WScript.Shell")
$shortcut = $WscriptObj.CreateShortcut($ShortcutPath)
$shortcut.TargetPath = $SourceFilePath
$shortcut.WindowStyle = 1
$ShortCut.Hotkey = "CTRL+SHIFT+T";
$shortcut.Save()`
```

This script works to do what I want when I run it in powershell on my PC, but I'm not sure how to get it to run on everyone else's. **We do not have access to group policy options** so we cannot use that method (I tried). Is there any way of doing this directly from PowerShell's AD commands?

I've tried using Group Policy Editor, but we do not have permission to use it at my workplace. As stated above, the script works when I run it, but only on my PC. So far I have been unable to find any other way of pushing this script to run en masse on other computers in the domain.

Comment: Split this problem into smaller parts and search for how to do those smaller parts. For example, "how to loop through an OU of computers in powershell", "how to run powershell script on remote computer"

Comment: You don't need a GPO to have something run for all users. Just copy it to all users startup folder, `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Comment: If you are an admin on all machines : $ShortcutPath = "\\machine\C$\Users\nameofplace.lnk"   The dollar sign instead of colon allow you to access folders/files on a remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

You could save your script and then call it using invoke-command

```
$computers = Get-AdComputer -Searchbase "OU=Location,OU=Corporate,DC=corp,DC=corporation,DC=com" -filter *

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers.Name -FilePath "C:\Scripts\MyScript.ps1"
```